# ¿Como crear tabla en SQL Server sin que registre logs de transacciones?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Actualmente tenemos la tabla "Comisiones_Temporal" en SQL Server que trae informacion de una tabla de otro servidor ( Usando servidores vinculados).

Se tiene previsto cargar 1 millon de registros al dia y borrarlos el mismo dia en la noche con TRUNCATE y repetir este proceso todos los dias. Averiguando me han dicho que si bien el truncate borra todo , talvez se llene los logs de la base de datos . Mi pregunta es :

¿Se pueden crear tablas que no registren logs en SQL Server ?  ¿ O no tendria que preocuparme por ello ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto no es algo que deba considerarse en entornos productivos. De por sí, no se deshabilita el logging, sólo se deja en modo SIMPLE. Pero el transaction log es requerido por el motor para funcionar. Truncate, por otra parte, no genera casi nada en log

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, no sabia que truncate no generaba log.

Comment: Sí genera log, pero es poco lo que se registra.

Comment: Comprendido, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todas las acciones en SQL Server se registran en el log de transacciones. Esto es para conservar la integridad de la información.

Por otro lado, `TRUNCATE TABLE` es una operación que registra poca información en el log de transacciones, ya que solo registra las páginas liberadas al vaciar la tabla. Es mucho más eficiente que un `DELETE`, el cual registra cada fila borrada.

Hablando de un millón de filas (no registros) al día, no es mucha información. Dependiendo de como esté configurado el log, no deberías de tener problemas. Los problemas serían si no se administra correctamente el log de transacciones creando respaldos continuos del mismo cuando la base de datos tiene el modelo de recuperación completo. En el caso de que el modelo de recuperación sea simple, la administración del log es más sencilla pero la capacidad de recuperar información en caso de un desastre es menor, así como ciertas funcionalidades de alta disponibilidad.

Comment: La recuperabilidad de la informacion de la tabla que menciono no es nada importante, puesto que es informacion que ya existe en otro lado y solo se esta copiando, asi que por ese lado no tengo problemas. Por otro lado tu respuesta me  ayuda bastante para poder realizar estas operaciones sin preocuparme por rendimientos o llenar los logs. Muchas gracias.

Comment: El modelo de recuperación se establece por base de datos, no por tabla. Esta y otras tablas pueden tener información desechable, pero otras tal vez no.